# Create the stripe token for the card but without using stripe element from the front-end side using Stripe V3

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, stripe-payments

I have created a token using stripe.createToken method for bank account using the following code.

```
stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  routing_number: '110000000',
  account_number: '000123456789',
  account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
  account_holder_type: 'individual',
}).then(function(result) {
  // Handle result.error or result.token
});
```

But I want to create the token for the card using same method `stripe.createToken`. In the following code, I have passed the card element.

```
stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
  // Handle result.error or result.token
});
```

But I don't want to pass the card element instead of this I want to pass the Card Information For e.g.:

```
stripe.createToken({
    cardNumber:'4242424242424242',
    cardExpiry:'06/22',
    cardCSV:'567'
       }).then(function(result) {
      // Handle result.error or result.token
    });
```

But this code is not working. Is there any way to pass the card information in the `stripe.createToken` method?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the stripe elements, keep a var referenced to the card number element.
Like so:

```
// this uses nuxtjs stripe library, but you'll understand the gist of this
var stripe = this.$stripe.import();
var stripe_elements = stripe.elements();
var card = {};
card.number = stripe_elements.create('cardNumber',{... styling classes..});
```

then when you want to create the token you:

```
var result = await stripe.createToken(card.number); // pass in the card.number variable created above from elements

console.log(result);
```

if the card is valid and everything's ok,
the log will bring back an object containing the token and other information like last4.

```
{
  "id": "tok_1g5is5GQVy7WmuRCB94a7QlHV",      // the token
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_125is1GvVy7zmuRCcDzjQy4g",   // card id 
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 11,
    "exp_year": 2022,
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "1234",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  .... . . ..
}
```